# Delete rows if cell in column B is in red color fill

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking for VBA that can delete rows if cell in column B contains red fill color.

Appreciate your help!

Comment: Show us what code you've got please

Answer (score 1):

This uses a specific Red *(ColorIndex #3)*

```
Sub BetterDeadThanRed()
    Dim N As Long
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = N To 1 Step -1
        If Cells(i, "B").Interior.ColorIndex = 3 Then
            Cells(i, "B").EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

**NOTE**

We run the loop from the bottom upwards.
This sub is not very fast.